# What is the reference property for a heading margin declared using rem?

Tags: html, css, html-heading, heading

The font-size of the body is 18px.

My headings are all declared as rem values. I want to have margin-bottom  as big as the line-height of each heading and margin-top twice as big as the line-height of each heading.

I thought I could achieve this by also using rem for the margins, but I actually don't know what root value is used for the margins of headings when you use 1rem. I'm getting 16px now.

Comment: Did you try searching for "rem css"? [This was the first result](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) and while I'm loathe to recommend w3schools, it does say that rem is relative to the font-size of the root element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rem`s are relative to the base font size which would be the font size set on the HTML element (usually 16px by default). It's generally advised to set the font size of the HTML element as a percentage to allow the user to set a font scaling setting in their browser for accessibility purposes. I personally tend to use `font-size: 62.5%` as that lets you think about `rem` units as `px / 10` so `1.6rem` would equal `16px` assuming the user has their browser font size set to `16px`.

Comment: I'm using wordpress and avada and they let you choose font-size for the body tag through the interface. I though defining font-size for the body was enough to use rem, but it wasn't. Now I just defined the margins for the html tag with CSS and the margins and heading sizes defined using rem follow the new value. So thanks!